# Can I prevent calling Fragment's constructor from the code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my `Fragment` I have a static `newInstance` method which takes some arguments, puts them in the `Bundle`, creates new `Fragment` with this `Bundle`:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(final CommandWithNumber command) {
    final CallsFragment fragment = new CallsFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(SHOW_DETAILS_COMMAND, command);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent calling `new CallsFragment()` in other places in the code and **force developers to use `newInstance` method?**

Of course, I can't make `CallsFragment` private because OS needs public one. Maybe there is a way to show warning or so, if someone tries to create an instance with the constructor?

Comment: may be you want to look into custom lint warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should **NOT** be using a Fragment's constructor for anything, the system uses it for restoring configuration changes.
there must be a public constructor that takes no arguments in a Fragment class

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

from the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

***EDIT:*** after discussing this further in the comment section and understanding what you want to do, you should add a `@Deprecated` annotation with javadocs saying why you shouldn't use this constructor internally, something like this:

```
/**
* this should <b>NEVER</b> be used, always use the newInstance method instead
**/
@Deprecated
public CallsFragment() {
  // EMPTY METHOD
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But is there a way to warn developer if he uses the constructor?

Comment: make a default constructor and add a `@Deprecated` annotation and add javadocs explaining why this is a bad idea. you can also get better programmers who read documentation and know what they should and shouldn't do

Comment: Please, write this comment as an answer and I'd accept it, because I think it is the best available solution